# MySQL query - joining 3 tables count and group by one column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the example of the 3 tables I'm working on

Orders

```
+----+----------+
| id | event_id |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 40       |
|  2 | 50       |
|  3 | 60       |
|  4 | 60       |
+----+----------+
```

Events

```
+----+------------+
| id | title      |
+----+------------+
|  40| Miserables |
|  50| Wicked     |
|  60| Christmas  |
+----+------------+
```

Order Items

```
+----+------------+----------+----------+
| id | order_id   | category | quantity |
+----+------------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 1          | VIP      |  2       |
| 2  | 1          | Gen Adm  |  5       |
| 3  | 2          | VIP      |  1       |
| 4  | 3          | Adult    |  1       |
| 5  | 3          | VIP      |  1       |
| 6  | 4          | VIP      |  3       |
| 7  | 4          | 4kids    |  2       |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

Desired Results

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| event_id | category   | count    |
+----------+------------+----------+
| 40       | VIP        |   2      |
| 40       | Gen Adm    |   5      |
| 50       | VIP        |   1      |
| 60       | Adult      |   1      |
| 60       | VIP        |   4      |
| 60       | 4kids      |   2      |
+----+-----------------------------+
```

I have tried this but not getting the desired result. Thanks again!

select orders.id, events.title, a.title from `events`
LEFT JOIN `orders` ON orders.event_id = events.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT order_id, category, SUM(quantity) as qty from order_items GROUP BY category) as a on a.order_id = orders.id
where orders.id is not null GROUP by a.category ORDER by events.title

Comment: Where did VIP with count 4 come from? There is no equivalent link between vip with quantity 1 then 3

Comment: The vip with quantity 1 then 3 is coming from orders id 3 and 4 as seen in orders item too

Comment: Yes but how are they supposed to combine into 4? Where does the link come from?

Comment: Your query looks nothing like your desired results. You aren't even choosing the columns that match your desired result, grouping by title makes no sense in the subquery. Can you start over?

Comment: orders id 3 & 4 bought the "Christmas" event tickets with 1 vip ticket coming from order id 3 and 3 vip tickets coming from order id 4. So I just want to combine them by category per events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery makes no sense to me. The entire query is as simple as:

`SELECT events.id, order_items.category, SUM(order_items.quantity) AS count FROM events left join orders on events.id=orders.event_id LEFT JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id = orders.id GROUP BY events.id, order_items.category`

I think the key here is that you want to group by two columns. Grouping by `event.id` should be the same as `event.title` as long as title is unique. But you also need to group by category to get the proper total. And since you want the count, you actually need to include that in the columns you select.

But, order.id is not the same as event.id, event.title is not the same as order_items.category, and `a.title` is not the count.

Comment: sorry I messed up the column name. little bit tired. it should be category instead of title. Thanks for the query, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward:

```
select event_id,category,sum(quantity) as count
from order_items
join orders on orders.id=order_items.order_id
group by event_id,category;
```